# How to resolve the error in reactjs project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

[error snaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUN3.png)

I am trying to run react project and run the project in terminal with npm start then i am getting error see this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUN3.png How to resolve this npm error.

Anyone help me out. how can we do that to fix this npm error

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, add nodejs to your path so something like:

> `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Also make sure you run npm from the correct directory of your project. Often you can be one folder too deep which causes errors too.

And finally, make sure npm is installed globally, also mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding the PATH to the ENVN variable manually.